# Gradle sync faild

Tags: java, android

How to fix it 
I use Android Studio
I tried to uninstall and reinstall sdk and did not work

shows errorCould not find `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3`.
Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.jar
```

Required by:
    project :app

how to change the Path for Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout 1.1.3 is not hosted on jcenter. Check that you have the **maven central** in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add more Activity in java folder but .does not work: how to check in build.gradle , in my menu it shows nothing such mavenCentral

Comment: Just double-click and edit it as any text file, non menu involved here.

Comment: sorry! I just added mavenCentral() but it shows again that it could not find it in  see message: Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:file:/C:/Users/rza/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom,

Comment: But is it searching now on maven central ?

Comment: after search shows: Elementtyp "application" musst be closes with the application but it is no application open!

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle (Module:app) go to dependencies, you will find this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

try changing it to

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

you might not have the latest 1.1.3 version installed yet

Comment: OK, but it's better to install it rather than downgrading.

Comment: Yes, i just wanted to locate where the problem came from. If it's resulting from older versions of the gradle, the obvious thing to do is to update it.

Comment: i changed for 3 to 0 and it is the ..: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}

Comment: did you sync the gradle after changing the constraint to 1.1.0, if so then what is the error that it gave you ?